# How can I write a package that has async methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to write a package that works in 2.7 and 3.x. The package needs to have methods that make post requests in an async way. Is this possible? I tried using request-futures, but I get an error when I try and make more than one request. I also tried grequests, but I couldn't even get that to make requests.

It would look something like this:

**my_package.py**

```
def _make_request(payload):
    requests.post(
        SERVICE_URL,
        data=json.dumps(payload),
    )

def do_thing_a():
    _make_request(some_payload)

def do_thing_b():
    _make_request(some_other_payload)
```

**code_that_uses_my_package.py**

```
    do_thing_a()
    do_thing_b()
```

If I use requests synchronously this works fine. If I use requests-futures, and just add the line 
`session = FuturesSession()` to each method and change requests.post to session.post, I get this error.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
<async at 0x3f657f0> failed with TypeError
```

If I only make one async call, it does work though. 
If I try grequests and use grequests.post + greqeuests.send, nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better library to use to do this?

Comment: Woiuld something like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) help?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer why grequests wasn't working for you. Using `grequests.send` is a little tricky, as the response object will be empty until the response gets back, so you'll need to keep checking the response object which is a little hacky. This is probably why it looked like it wasn't doing anything at all.

Use `grequests.map` instead; it won't block while it's waiting for the response but it won't execute the next line until all the requests return. If you have multiple requests, you send them together with `grequests.map`and they will run asynchronously. Here's an example with your code sample:

```
def _make_request(payload):
    return grequests.post(
        SERVICE_URL,
        data=json.dumps(payload),
    )

def do_thing_a():
    return _make_request(some_payload)

def do_thing_b():
    return _make_request(some_other_payload)

reqs = [do_thing_a(), do_thing_b()]
grequests.map(reqs)
print reqs[0].response, reqs[1].response
```

`req` doesn't have to include multiple requests, it can be a list with a single element. Look at `grequests.imap` if you're interested in getting the responses for multiple requests as they come in.